# Adding 'x' lines to a SQL Table based on user input

Tags: sql-server, vue.js

I have an application that has editable table rows through Vue that are displayed from a database. As of right now there is a button (add line) that when clicked calls a query to insert a row into a database. Is there a way to take user input to automatically add x number of lines without having to click the (add line) button many times?

This is the front end button:

```
input(style="margin-right: 50px;" type="submit" value="Add Line  " @click="addLine(query_number)")
```

This is Vue function that calls the backend query

```
addLine(query_number) {
  let line = {
    "quote_number": this.query_number
  }

  this.$http.post(`/api/quote/line/?quote_number=${query_number}`, line).then(res => {
    if(res.data.error) {
      this.$root.updateError(res.data.error)
    } else {
      this.$router.go(`/quote/line/?quote_number=${query_number}`), this.$root.updateSuccess(res.data.message)
    }
  }).catch(error => {
    this.$root.updateError(error)
  })
},
```

And finally the post call:

```
.post(checkAuthentication, (req, res) => {
  let request = new sql.Request(pool)
  let add_newLine = `
  insert into quote_line (
    quote_number,
    line_number,
    item_id,
    created_at
  )
  output Inserted.*
  Values (
    ${req.query.quote_number},
    ((select count(quote_number) as [count]
      from quote_line
      where quote_number = ${req.query.quote_number || ''}) + 1),
    'new item line',
    getDate()
  )`

  request.query(add_newLine, (error, result) => {
    if(error) {
      throw new Error(error)
      res.json({"error": `${error}`})
    }
    res.json({"message": `Successfully added a new line to ${req.query.quote_number}`})
  })
})
```

Comment: You need to show us your existing code in order for us to assist you.

Comment: Unless you're going for updating the database in real time, I'd suggest considering having new rows exist only client side until changes are explicitly submitted; as a side benefit, that kind of design gives a rudimentary undo in the form of revert (changes made since last save).

Answer (score 0):

Create a UI element where the user can input the number of rows to add, and either modify the function that currently adds a row to add multiple, or call it in a loop, based on that input.

As Dale said, we'd probably need to see code to help further.